# Excel VBA "If","Or" and "And" partially working

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have code that loops through cells and fills the cell based on an if statement that contains the `Or` function and then the `And` function.

The code is partially working, the `Or` section is working but the `And` section is  being ignored and the cells are being filled only on the basis of the `Or` section only.

Can someone help so that the code factors in the `And` function and not just the `Or` section.

Below is the code in question.

```
Sub MarkUp()
    Worksheets("TO_Project").Activate

    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 24) = Date
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 25).Value = DateAdd("d", 30, ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 24))

    MarkUpLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("f100000").End(xlUp).Row

    For RowCount = 2 To MarkUpLastRow
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCount, 4) = "01 Prospect" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCount, 4) = "02 Capture" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCount, 4) = "03 Proposal" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCount, 4) = "04 Submitted" And ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCount, 16) < ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 24) Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCount, 16).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        End If
    Next RowCount
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/operator-precedence), your condition is parsed as:

```
If _
  (ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCount, 4) = "01 Prospect") _
  Or (ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCount, 4) = "02 Capture") _
  Or (ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCount, 4) = "03 Proposal") _
  Or (ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCount, 4) = "04 Submitted" And ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCount, 16) < ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 24))
```

Apparently you meant:

```
If _
  (ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCount, 4) = "01 Prospect" _
   Or ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCount, 4) = "02 Capture" _
   Or ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCount, 4) = "03 Proposal" _
   Or ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCount, 4) = "04 Submitted") _
  And (ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCount, 16) < ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 24))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this construction:
(condition OR condition OR condition) AND condition